# Custom field accessor in spring mvc instead of beanWrapper

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I've setup a basic spring boot web mvc application with an expression on my view like this:

```
${foo.bar}
```

The Foo object has a structure like this:

```
  public class Foo {


    public String get(String name){
        return "something calclulated";
    }

    public void set(String name, String value){
        doSomething(name, value);
    }
}
```

My JSTL Expression fails because Foo does not contain a getter for bar, which I cannot implement for structural reasons.

Is it possible to add a custom field accessor to spring, which uses my "get" and "set" method instead of looking for a right getter or setter if I try to access a bean of type Foo?

Something like this:

```
public class FooAccessor {

   getFieldValue(String fieldName, Foo target){
     return target.get(fieldName);
   }


   setFieldValue(String fieldName, String fieldValue, Foo target){
       target.set(fieldName, fieldValue)
   }
}
```

After some research I found the interface PropertyAccessor, which is also used by the class BeanWrapperImpl

Unfortunately I didn't find any example or solution on how to add my custom field accessor.

Comment: JSP EL has supported passing args for some time. Can't you just do `${foo.get("bar")}`

Comment: That would be possible if I only use it for displaying data. My goal is to use class "Foo" as a model so I can bind it in a form. If I use the function get() inside JSTL I cannot use other binding features and have to map each write operation in my controller on my own.

Comment: Create a simple wrapper class the delegates to the Foo class `public class FooWrapper{

 private Foo foo;
 
 public FooWrapper(Foo foo){
  this.foo =foo;
 }
 
 public void getBar(){
  return foo.someMethod();
 }
 
 public void setBar(String bar){
   foo.someMethod(bar);
 }
}`

Comment: Thank you for your idea. This would be possible, but then I loose my intention to have a generic setter because I have to implement one setter for each property.